# Recursively Applying SVN Properties

Tags: svn

If I apply a Subversion property recursively to a top-level folder (the top of the repository, for example) but I don't have all the children checked out, will the property still get recursively applied?

The reason I ask is because I have an enormous repository to apply svn:ignore to (recursively), but I don't want to check out every folder underneath it due to time constraints.  I want to make sure the setting is still going to apply to the children.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you need to apply the property to all the children, you can do so with `--recursive` but you need to actually have the children in your working copy.

Comment: The answer I wasn't hoping to hear, but it's good that I know.  Thanks, Michael.